# Google analytics accuracy -- Why am I seeing my real time activity but not that activity in other reporting?

Tags: google-analytics

I have just started using google analytics on my website. When I look at the real time section as I visit my site, it always shows an active user. I have done this many times now. However in the other sections it only shows that I have visited the site once. Any ideas why this would be?

Comment: If your site is not live yet, and you know there can be no other users, then the active user would likely be yourself, if you are not filtering out your own IP. In the standard reports, you would see only one visit as the cookie has likely not been deleted. If you were to delete your cookie and revisit your site, then this would counted as a new visit and a new visitor.

Comment: Which metric are you looking at? Session, User?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a reporting delay of 24hrs in the main reporting section. Real-time is as accurate as possible, but should only be used as informational.

Also, consider making two views on your account. One should be titled 'Raw Data' and not contain any filters. The second view should be a filtered version that excludes your own IP from traffic reports.

Answer (score 1):

We have found that GA is not accurate up to about 48 hours after the event. So, if you want accurate stats for 30th March, check on the 1st of April.

If you look at really granular information it can even change within that period so don't rely on it being 100% accurate until after it has "settled".

Also, a good idea to filter out your IP so that you don't get false information.